# Android 4.2 - Creating new project and try to import the same gives- Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

**Steps**:

1.Create new same project and Open in Android pane
2.Import same project without closing first pane in Android Pane

This throws Null pointer exception

**Note: I have tried in multiple system creating sample project but gives same NPE.Is it issue with Android Studio 4.2 ?**

[image]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.GradleSyncStats$Builder.setTrigger(GradleSyncStats.java:3154)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncEventLogger.generateSyncEvent(GradleSyncEventLogger.kt:97)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.generateSyncEvent(GradleSyncState.kt:151)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl.reportToUsageTracker(SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl.kt:37)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssuesReporter.lambda$report$4(SyncIssuesReporter.java:110)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:201)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:328)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:132)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:188)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:499)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)**strong text**
```

Comment: Try to reinstall the android studio or try File>Invalidate caches/Restart

Comment: Tried it is not working,
Also tried in different system but facing same issue